# Windows 10 search option does not work

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I have this issue for a while, when I try to type in the search box (Cortana as they say), nothing appears in the text box and it seems like disabled or frozen.

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 0):

Several suggestions we can try to fix this issue:

Method 1: Create new user profile

If the new user profile can work fine with Search box and then we can repair current corrupted user profile for fixing.

https://windowsreport.com/corrupt-user-profile-windows-10/

Method 2: Register the Start Menu and Cortana components by using powershell commands:

```
Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```